# PowerShell CLI VMware View Cmdlets to create a userlist with entitlements

Tags: powershell, vmware, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to get a list of users and/or groups with their entitlements from the VMware View cmdlets.  So far I have this but I am not sure how to use the Get-HVEntitlement cmdlet properly, I have only found examples based on a specific username.  I also can't seem to get the VMware.VimAutomation.HorizonView cmdlets to show up at all, only the VMware.Hv.Helper cmdlets even though the modules are loading.

```
Import-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI
Import-Module -Name VMware.VimAutomation.HorizonView
Import-Module -Name VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Import-Module -Name VMware.Hv.Helper

Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -ProxyPolicy NoProxy -Confirm

Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -Scope User -ParticipateInCEIP $false
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore
connect-hvserver servername
```

Comment: Have you seen the documentation page for that function already? It may contain some examples on how to better use the `Get-HVEntitlement` function: https://github.com/vmware/PowerCLI-Example-Scripts/blob/master/Modules/VMware.Hv.Helper/docs/Get-HVEntitlement.md

Answer (score 1):

For the modules, try:

```
Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.HorizonView
Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Import-Module -Name VMware.Hv.Helper
```

For listing the users and pools, you'd have to use a combination of Get-HVPool and Get-HVEntitlement.

Something like this:

```
$Connection = Connect-HVServer -Server $server -User $user -Password $Password -Domain $domain
                
                $capture = $Connection.ExtensionData
if ($capture)
{

    Get-HVPool | ForEach-Object -Process {
                $currentpool = $_
                
                $entitlements = Get-HVEntitlement -ResourceName $currentpool.Base.Name |
                
                ForEach-Object -Process {
                    
                    $_.Base.LoginName
                    
                }
                
                '' | Select @{ Name = 'Pool'; Expression = { $currentpool.Base.Name } },
                
                            @{ Name = 'Entitlement'; Expression = { $entitlements -join ',' } }
                
            }}
```

PS, take a look at VDIBot already built (exe coming soon): https://communities.vmware.com/message/2988686#2988686